# Clamping degree values to 0 <= x < 360 algebraically

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

Given the function:

```
void Arc::SetAngles(double startAngle, double endAngle) {
    while(endAngle > (startAngle + 359.0)) endAngle -= 1.0;
    while(startAngle > 360.0) startAngle -= 360.0;
    while(startAngle < -360.0) startAngle += 360.0;
    while(endAngle > 360.0) endAngle -= 360.0;
    while(endAngle < -360.0) endAngle += 360.0;
    _startAngle = DegreeToRadian(startAngle);
    _endAngle = DegreeToRadian(endAngle);
}
```

Is there an algebraic solution to those while loops? It just looks...ugly. (Not to mention...slow.)

Comment: If an accuracy of 0.005 degrees is enough (for anything I've ever written, it is!), you could consider storing your angles as `uint16_t` (with 65535 = 360°). The beauty of this is that you can save all those calculations and simply let the value overflow (plus, it takes less storage, which admittedly doesn't matter so much today as it did in the 1980s...).

Comment: @mu is too short: As always, it depends. A single value will probably not save any room due to padding (and saving 6 bytes is mostly ridiculous nowadays anyway). On the other hand, this may _just_ make a larger `struct` fit into a cache line whereas otherwise it would split on cache lines! Or, you might need to iterate over an array of 10,000-20,000 angles. In one case, this will fit into L1, in the other it won't. The same goes for conversions and calculations. If you add a single angle and then call a dozen stdlib trig funcs, it is probably not worth the trouble. In the opposite case, it is.

Comment: @mu is too short: The main advantage of this 80s style hack is not so much to save memory anyway (at least, not nowadays with computers having literally gigabytes of main memory). The main advantage is that overflow automatically wraps values into a valid range. Assign any value, add, subtract, whatever... the output is always valid. Just when using a standard trig func, you need _one_ conversion.

Comment: @mu: ITYM how many *angles* can dance ;-). If you're creating a big old array, chances are that `uint16_t` will be 1/4 the size of `double`, and occupy 1/4 the space: there's no "wastage" in an array of `uint16_t` (guaranteed), or of structs that contain only `uint16_t` (expected but not guaranteed). Big old arrays are where you start to care about memory use for its own sake, not because of cache performance. If your struct goes `double; uint16_t; double; uint16_t` or something, that's when alignment can kill any hopes of saving space compared with 4 doubles. So don't do that :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C or C++ you'd use [`fmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmod.html) to get rid of some of your loops. Instead of this:

```
while(startAngle > 360.0) startAngle -= 360.0;
while(startAngle < -360.0) startAngle += 360.0;
```

Do this:

```
startAngle = fmod(startAngle, 360.0);
if(startAngle < 0)
    startAngle += 360.0;
```

Don't use the normal modulus operator (`%`) as that's for integers and won't do the right thing with floating point values.

Your first loop:

```
while(endAngle > (startAngle + 359.0)) endAngle -= 1.0;
```

Can be replaced with just this:

```
if(endAngle > startAngle + 359.0)
    endAngle = startAngle + 359.0;
```

But I think you should rethink that part of your algorithm: there's no point in comparing the angles before you normalize them to the [0,360) interval.

Answer (score 2):

with modulus ?

```
angle = mod(angle,360.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use modulus, which divides by 360 but returns the remainder instead of the result of the division: `380 mod 360 = 20`. Do note that `-380 mod 360 = -20`

Comment: The sign will depend on the language

Comment: The answer for "Is there an algebraic solution" does not include language-specific elements per se, but http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation mentions them for the most common ones (c++ tag added later)

Answer (score 0):

Does your language have a modulus operator that works for floating point? The % in Java. This gives the remainder when dividing by a number.

```
startAngle = startAngle % 360.0
```

(Yes the concept of a remainder is weird when applied to floating point numbers, but Java at least does give a useful definition.)

Contrary to the comments below, in Java % is explictly defined in the language specification:

> 15.17.3 Remainder Operator %
>
> In C and C++, the remainder operator
>   accepts only integral operands, but in
>   the Java programming language, it also
>   accepts floating-point operands.

See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html for the full details. Bottom line I believe that this can be used to  implement the required algorithms.

Comment: In C or C++ I'm pretty sure `%` would make a mess of things (hence `fmod` in the standard math library), I don't know about Java.

Comment: @mu, @Oli: not what the spec says. I include the reference now. Do you think your -1 is still merited?

Comment: That covers the Java side of things(which I didn't know about and even said as much) but the question has been marked C++ since we answered so what the Java standard says is suddenly OT.

Comment: @mu: yes good point, and I didn't think to check the C language spec when I posted. Thanks.

Comment: C and C++ have `fmod`, so while it's true that the `%` operator only takes integer operands, it doesn't matter in practice unless you're writing generic code that works with either integers or floating point types. In that case I suppose you'd have to tediously write an overloaded function to calculate modulus.